# JS sort array object by custom key and value

Tags: javascript, sorting

I am fresh JS student and I found a problem which I can't sole by my self. I've got an array of objects and one of the key of these objects is 'priority' and values for that key are: "low", "mid", "high". I would like to sort my objects in array from the lowest priority to the highest, but I can't figure it out.

```
let thingsToDo = [
  {
  name: 'Call',
  priority: 'low',
},
  {
  name: 'Cook',
  priority: 'low',
  },
    {
  name: 'Eat',
  priority: 'high',
  },
                {
  name: 'Sleep',
  priority: 'mid',
  }
];
```

I was trying to make some custom sort function, but i don't know how to do it. What I think would be a good solution is giving these values some number and then sort it. Very important for me is to leave these values as a string. There has to be `priority: "low"`

I've been looking for solution sometime and I didn't found it.

I have no idea how to do it, so if there is some good person with a bigger experience, I beg for help.

Comment: This is a variant of the [Dutch national flag problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_national_flag_problem). I'll leave figuring out how to apply the solution as an exercise to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place all the priorities in an array and sort the object's based on the index of their priority property in that array.

```js
let thingsToDo = [
  {
  name: 'Call',
  priority: 'low',
},
  {
  name: 'Cook',
  priority: 'low',
  },
    {
  name: 'Eat',
  priority: 'high',
  },
                {
  name: 'Sleep',
  priority: 'mid',
  }
];
let priorities = ['low', 'mid', 'high'];
thingsToDo.sort((a, b)=>priorities.indexOf(a.priority) - priorities.indexOf(b.priority));
console.log(thingsToDo);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Its working but is there any way to do it without creating a new array with priorities?

Comment: @Sebastian What exactly are you looking for? How would you sort it if you don't define an order somewhere?

Comment: Yee... right now I understand it. I was thinking about creating some kind of sub value for priority key but it looks like it doesn't work that way :P Like I said I just started to learn JS so my question might be stupid. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object that maps them to comparable values and then sort based on the them:

```
const priority = {
    low: 1,
    mid: 2,
    high: 3,
};

thingsToDo.sort(
    (a, b) => priority[a.priority] - priority[b.priority]
);
```

Here is a working snippet:

```js
let thingsToDo = [
    {
        name: 'Call',
        priority: 'low',
    },
    {
        name: 'Cook',
        priority: 'low',
    },
    {
        name: 'Eat',
        priority: 'high',
    },
    {
        name: 'Sleep',
        priority: 'mid',
    },
];

const priority = {
    low: 1,
    mid: 2,
    high: 3,
};

thingsToDo.sort(
    (a, b) => priority[a.priority] - priority[b.priority]
);

console.log(thingsToDo)
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm almost there but i would like to sort thingsToDo array witout creating new one with priorities. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: Do you mean  `thingsToDo = thingsToDo.sort((a, b) => priority[a.priority] - priority[b.priority]
);` ?

Comment: Okey. Now I know my question was stupid. Your first answer is the way to do it. I was thinking about creating some new sub value to 'priority' inside of thingsToDo array

Answer (score 0):

try it

const fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fruits.sort();

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).